# Nullable integer as part of composite primary key

Tags: innodb, mariadb, primary-key, null, default-value

I want to store phone numbers as integers and I've created this SQL:

```sql
DROP TABLE `user_id_phone`;
CREATE TABLE `user_id_phone`
(
    `user_id`      int     unsigned  NOT NULL,
    `country_code` smallint unsigned NOT NULL,
    `number`       bigint unsigned   NOT NULL,
    `ext`          smallint unsigned NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`country_code`, `number`, `ext`)    
) ENGINE = InnoDB
```

But my server (10.4.14-MariaDB) creates field `ext` as 'NOT NULL':

```sql
`ext` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
```

if `ext` is a part of the composite primary key:

```sql
PRIMARY KEY (`country_code`, `number`, `ext`)
```

In case of `ext` is not a part of the primary key:

```sql
PRIMARY KEY (`country_code`, `number`),
```

the field DDL is right after creation:

```sql
  `ext` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
```

Why?

Comment: Recommend using standard 2-letter country_codes instead of smallint.

Answer (score 3):

> Why?

Because you can't have NULL values in a primary key. Why? Because the SQL standard says so:

> If the <unique specification> specifies PRIMARY KEY, then for each <column name> in the explicit or implicit <unique column list> for which NOT NULL is not specified, NOT NULL is implicit in the <column definition>.

This is also [described in documentation](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/primary-keys-with-nullable-columns/).

PS. Phone numbers are not integers and should not be stored as such. They are character sequences that often, but not always, contain mostly digits.